# Handling events in Custom View (drawing on Canvas) using button widgets

Tags: java, android

Sorry for my English first of all. I have a CustomView where I draw shapes using Canvas. I need when I click on the buttons on the screen were drawn squares. Why when I click on the buttons nothing happens?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        CustomView mView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mView = new CustomView(this);
        }

        public void mButton1(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(1);
        }

        public void mButton2(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(2);
        }

        public void mButton3(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(3);
        }
    }
```

**CustomView**

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private int drawingSquare = 0;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);
        if (drawingSquare == 1) {
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-125, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2-75, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        } else if (drawingSquare == 2) {
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-25, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+25, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        } else if (drawingSquare == 3) {
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2+75, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+125, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        }
    }

    public void drawSquare(int mSquareNumber) {
        this.drawingSquare = mSquareNumber;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.stackoverflow.myapplication.CustomView
            android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="mButton1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="mButton2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="mButton3" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not invalidating same view as used in activity.

You need to do findViewById and it will work. All other code is written fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        CustomView mView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mView = findViewById(R.id.myCustomView);
        }

        public void mButton1(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(1);
        }

        public void mButton2(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(2);
        }

        public void mButton3(View view) {
            mView.drawSquare(3);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need something in your custom view that handles touch events (with [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent))), checks the coordinates of the touch events, and responds to those events the way you want.  None of this happens automatically for custom views.  You will have to learn to write the code.